# Magento grid not fully displayed

Tags: magento2, admin, grid

I have Installed Magento 2.4.5 but grids on the admin side are all right aligned ( not displaying on full screen )

[image]

Comment: Check Magneto console or log file for the real error.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya getting these kind of errors in logs, Broken reference: the 'page.actions.toolbar' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'page.main.actions' and '' respectively. [] []

Comment: If any third party extension or something install then, disable that from config.php and then run all the commands and then check.

Comment: Thank you issue solved @DhirenVasoya

Answer (score 1):

It is caused by installing third-party extensions or sometimes users' own custom extensions. I would suggest disabling those if you have made any custom modules or installed extensions, by running the `bin/magento module:disable <NAME>` or from the `config.php` file located in `app/etc` folder.

After that, run the `bin/magento setup:upgrade` command and it should be fixed.